# How to create a footer that is always the last thing on the page using float layout

Tags: css, xhtml, css-float, footer

just like the question states, how to keep the footer div as the last element showing on a page using float layout, and regardless of the amount of content preceding the footer.

Comment: Check out http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place the following at the end of your code (before `</body>`)

```
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
#footer{ clear:both; }
```

Comment: that didn't work.  And if i resize the webpage like zooming in and stuff, the footer overlaps its previous content.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I use to [keep footers at the bottom of the page](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page).

Answer (score 1):

What Angelo R. said should work but it may depend on the rest of your structure. If you for example have some kind of a holder with n floated elements inside and you set the last element (your footer) to have no float and clear:both it should clear the above floats and seat on the bottom. The other example might be that you have some floated elements inside a holder and the footer is beneath and outside that holder you should make sure that the elements inside that holder are cleared by adding overflow:hidden to that holder or use some kind of clearfix, because if the floats that holder contains are not cleared he will collapse no mater what property you add to your footer.